# model.fit_generator() shape error

Tags: python, keras

```
import os
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense

img_width, img_height = 64, 64

train_data_dir = 'data/train'
validation_data_dir = 'data/validation'
nb_train_samples = sum([len(files) for files in os.walk(train_data_dir)])
nb_validation_samples = sum([len(files) for files in os.walk(validation_data_dir)])
nb_epoch = 10


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4096, input_dim = 4096, init='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4,init='normal',activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        )


test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        color_mode="grayscale",
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=1,
        class_mode=None)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_data_dir,
        color_mode="grayscale",
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=1,
        class_mode=None)

model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        samples_per_epoch=nb_train_samples,
        nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        nb_val_samples=nb_validation_samples)
```

Everything runs fine until the model.fit_generator() in the coding above. Then it pop out errors like the the followed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sam/PycharmProjects/MLP/Testing Code without CNN.py", line 55, in <module>
    nb_val_samples=nb_validation_samples)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 874, in fit_generator
    pickle_safe=pickle_safe)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1427, in fit_generator
    'or (x, y). Found: ' + str(generator_output))
Exception: output of generator should be a tuple (x, y, sample_weight) or (x, y). Found: [[[[ 0.19215688]
```

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? Could you provide examples?

Answer (score 1):

The problem should be caused by data dimension mismatch. `ImageDataGenerator` actually loads image files and put into numpy array in shape of (num_image_channel, image_height, image_width). But your first layer is a densely connected layer, which is looking for input data in the shape of 1D array, or 2D array with a number of samples. So essentially you are missing your input layer, which takes the input in the right shape.

Change the following line of code

```
model.add(Dense(4096, input_dim = 4096, init='normal', activation='relu'))
```

to

```
model.add(Reshape((img_width*img_height*img_channel), input_shape=(img_channel, img_height, img_width)))
model.add(Dense(4096, init='normal', activation='relu'))
```

You have to define `img_channel`, which is the number of channels in your images. The above code also assumes that your are using `dim_ordering` of `th`. If you are using `tf` input dimension ordering, you would have to change the input reshape layer to

```
model.add(Reshape((img_width*img_height*img_channel), input_shape=(img_height, img_width, img_channel)))
```

--- Old answer --

You probably have put training data and validation data into subfolders under `train` and `validation`, which isn't supported by `Keras`. All training data should be in one single folder, same for the validation data.

Please refer to [this Keras tutorial](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) for more details.

Comment: The [documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) uses the same directory structure as in the code given in the question.

Comment: These two lines of code may be problematic. `nb_train_samples = sum([len(files) for files in os.walk(train_data_dir)])
nb_validation_samples = sum([len(files) for files in os.walk(validation_data_dir)])`

The OP needs to check the output.

Comment: Don't think that this should be a problem, it just returns an integer.

Comment: My understanding is that `len(files)` will output 3 under such use, since `files` is actually a tuple of length 3. But I agree this should be giving the error though.

Comment: It will return a list of 3s, so the number of files will be too high but you are right, that's probably not the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The training data and validation data are classified into sub-folders for classification of the images. About the data dimension mismatch, can u give some advice on how to match the inputs from the images to the first layer and lastly to the fit_generator?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include code for your reference. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve but if you are trying a binary classification of pictures, try setting `class_mode` to `binary`. From the [documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/):

> class_mode: one of "categorical", "binary", "sparse" or None. Default:
>   "categorical". Determines the type of label arrays that are returned:
>   "categorical" will be 2D one-hot encoded labels, "binary" will be 1D
>   binary labels, "sparse" will be 1D integer labels.

The error message is a bit confusing but if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/pull/2991/files), it becomes clearer:

```
if not hasattr(generator_output, '__len__'):
                    _stop.set()
                    raise Exception('output of generator should be a tuple '
                                    '(x, y, sample_weight) '
                                    'or (x, y). Found: ' + str(generator_output))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am trying to categorize images according to the sub-folders in the train and validation folders and it has a total of 4 sub-folders. i have tried using class_mode of None, categorical and binary. None gives the error above while categorical gives this error.
>> Exception: Error when checking model input: expected dense_input_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1L, 64L, 64L, 1L)
Any idea on how to solve it?